# Как переделать json на jsonp?

Tags: json, php, ajax

Как из этого сделать кроссдоменный запрос?

```
function NotificationOmena(){
 $.ajax({
        url: "http://omena.kz/omenaAjax.php",
        dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        var row = data[i];
                        if(row.rid == 1){notification_test.cancel()}
                                    function createNotificationInstance(options){
                                        if(options.notificationType == 'simple'){
                                            return window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
                                                'http://localhost/omena/icon.png','Вам ответили на сайте '+row.hostname,row.msg
                                            );
                                        }
                                    }
                            
                           
                                  if(window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 0) {
                                    notification_test = createNotificationInstance({notificationType: 'simple'});
                                        notification_test.show();
                                  } else {
                                    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
                                  }
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: "id=" + row.id,
                                    url: "/omena/hide.php",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    success: function(data){
                                    }
                                });

                        }              
          }
    });     
}



function OmenaSelect(){
        $uid = $_SESSION['uid']; 
        $sql = "SELECT msg,id,rid,hostname FROM msg WHERE uid='$uid' AND rid=''";
        $result = $this->_db->query($sql);
        $data = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

на

```
if ( preg_match("/^(?!\\d)\\w+$/", $_GET['callback']) ) {
    echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($data).");";
} else {
    echo json_encode($data);
};
```

Comment: Спасибо вот только первый скрипт не срабатывает выдаёт ошибку data.length мол ругаетсЯ

Comment: У ошибки есть конкретный текст, который падает в консоль.